# Laravel with Docker "laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, docker

Suddenly I started to get this error, and I cannot work on the app at all. Once the error got fixed by itself, but now that I opened the project today, I started to get it again.

I tried changing the permissions, as we can see here, but did not make the trick:

`drwxrwxr-x 8 root www-data 256 Jul 7 08:25 storage`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

`chown -R www-data storage`

- Make www-data the owner.